# Creating Image instance from drawable images in android

Tags: android, itext, signature

i am creating digital signature app using `iTextG jar`, to add water mark on the signature field, iText's

```
appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(signedImagePath));
```

Requires a path of the watermark image, i want to use image from drawable folder of android, kindly suggest me i am not getting how to create Image instance from drawable, suggest if any other option is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use ImageInstance something like this.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.yourimage);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources, int, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)